# Abstract recycler fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, android-recyclerview, abstract

I'm trying to create an abstract fragment class that sets up a recycler view. This is the relevant part of my adapter:

```
class PeopleAdapter(context: Context?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleAdapter.PersonViewHolder>() {

    inner class PersonViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is the abstract fragment:

```
abstract class RecyclerFragment : Fragment() {

    protected abstract fun createAdapter(context: Context?): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val adapter = createAdapter(context)
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter

        // ...
    }
}
```

This is how I'd like to use it:

```
class PeopleFragment : RecyclerFragment() {

    override fun createAdapter(context: Context?): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        return PeopleAdapter(context)
    }
}
```

Android Studio throws an error on `return PeopleAdapter(context)`:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is PeopleAdapter but
>   RecyclerView.Adapter was expected

I don't understand why it's a problem. `PersonAdapter` extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and `PersonViewHolder` extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, so isn't it implied that `PersonAdapter` extends `RecyclerView.Adapater<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`?

I tried changing the `createAdapter` method as follows:

```
protected abstract fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder?> createAdapter(context: Context?): RecyclerView.Adapter<T>
```

I changed the implementation also:

```
override fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder?> createAdapter(context: Context?): RecyclerView.Adapter<T> {
    return PeopleAdapter(context)
}
```

This time, the error is:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is PeopleAdapter but
>   RecyclerView.Adapter was expected

Again, I'm expecting the types to line up but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your generic types in the abstract class, and provide them in the concrete implementation :

```
class PeopleAdapter(context: Context?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleAdapter.PersonViewHolder>() {

        inner class PersonViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
 }

abstract class RecyclerFragment<VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, out T :  RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>> : Fragment() {

    protected abstract fun createAdapter(context: Context?): T

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val adapter = createAdapter(context)
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter

        // ...
    }
}

class PeopleFragment : RecyclerFragment<PeopleAdapter.PersonViewHolder, PeopleAdapter>() {

    override fun createAdapter(context: Context?): PeopleAdapter {
        return PeopleAdapter(context)
    }
}
```

The closest you could get currently is an unchecked cast :

`return PeopleAdapter(context) as RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`